# Strange output when printing an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting a very strange output when I print my empty object in my test.js file.

This is my code

```
var resultObj = {};

console.log(resultObj);
```

In command line I do node test.js and my output is

```
äå
```

I am using sublime text but I always have so not sure what changed. When I go to my browser and type the same code my output is correct and it shows `{}` but when I run the code locally I get that strange output. Is it due to the editor I am using? I never had that issue in the past though so I am just very curious in terms of what could have changed?

Comment: What application are you running this command line under, or are you saying a command line integrated with sublime text?

Comment: @Jacob i am running the command line on regular terminal on mac. I do node test.js and i get that strange output.

Comment: To the Person who has flagged this question to close. How come? I am not specific enough? Please make suggestions.

Comment: Are you using any exotic shells, or is it a typical `bash` or `zsh`?

Comment: How do you run your code? `node test.js` ?

Comment: @Jacob i was using bash but when i switched to normal terminal it is printing the correct output. I wanna credit you with the answer please post it as an answer.

Comment: I thought you posted earlier that you were already using the regular terminal on Mac.

Comment: @Jacob i was but i noticed the title said bash so i guess maybe i had switched over time but that still does not explain why the strange output haha but oh well.

Comment: It seems like a character set issue to me. I think it logged out `{}` but using some encoding mismatch between the terminal emulator and application. The `äå` characters are adjacent as are `{}`, so this is some translation issue most likely. Still haven't found an "ah ha" thing to point to, but knowing which terminal application you were using before and after would help.

Comment: @Jacob hmm yeah very strange, never ran in to this before.

Comment: So can you answer the question on what you were using before you used the Mac terminal application?

Comment: If you had a Swedish keyboard layout, and tried typing {} as if it were a US keyboard layout, you'd get äå.